# Использование @hide в javadoc

Tags: java, android, android-library, javadoc, android-interface

Не раз встречался с аннотацией `@hide` в *Javadoc*. Известно что эта аннотация запрещает доступ к методу после релиза (доступ всё так же можно получить через рефлексию).

У меня появилась необходимость объявить **интерфейс *публичным*** для доступа из другого `package`, но при этом не дать возможность его использовать конечному пользователю. Есть ли какая нибудь возможность воспользоваться этой аннотацией или аналогом с подобным функционалом?

Исходя из [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798933/hide-method-class-using-hide-in-annotation), это реализовать невозможно, но так как ответ был дан в 2014 году, есть надежда, что положение дел изменилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно понимаете `@hide`. На ваш код `@hide` не оказывает никакого влияния вообще (как до релиза, так и после - чтобы это не значило в вашем вопросе). `@hide` используется только при генерации `android.jar` - библиотеки с заглушками.

Что касается проблемы видимости:

1. Скрыть публичный интерфейс нельзя.
2. Возможно, получится все реализации интерфейса перенести в тот же пакет что и сам интерфейс. Это решит проблему видимости.
3. Можно оставить видимость `package` и везде где нужен экземпляр класса использовать рефлексию `Class.forName(...)`
4. Если у вас есть доступ к процессу компиляции, то можно для написания кода использовать "нерабочую" jar с заглушками, а в момент компиляции подменять на полноценный jar со всеми файлами.

P.S. Публичный интерфейс это даже хорошо. Вдруг кому-то понадобится написать его собственную реализацию данного интерфейса.

---

**Пояснения к пункту 4 :**

Если вы делаете публичную библиотеку, то хотите чтобы сторонние программисты видели только некоторые функции и класс, или хотите скрыть реализацию функций и ресурсы и т.д.. С помощью `public/private/protected` скрыть всё что вы хотите невозможно. Поэтому иногда используют метод под названием `stub.jar` он же `dummy code`. Этот метод является основой подхода "Skeleton programming".

Заключается он в том, что в проект стороннего программиста вместо вашей библиотеки добавляется `stub.jar` - это библиотека из которой вырезана реализация методов, ресурсы, скрытые классы и методы - всё то, что сторонний программист не должен видеть. Такой `jar` можно написать самому или сгенерировать чем-нибудь типа Stubber. Кончено такой `jar` неработоспособен - там только заглушки.

Зачем это нужно - сторонний программист не видит ваши скрытые классы, алгоритмы шифрования и т.д., но при этом он может писать, **компилировать**, и тестировать свой код так как-будто использует вашу библиотеку.

Чтобы получить готовый продукт нужно перед компиляцией подменить `stub.jar` на рабочую библиотеку. Как это сделать зависит от вашей системы сборки. Можно подменять руками - удалять старый jar и добавлять новый, можно использовать системы сборки типа Gradle например так:

```
task replaceStubs() {
  delete fileTree(dir: 'libs' , include: '**/*_Stub.jar')
  copy {
        from `MyRelaseLibsFolder`
        into `libs`
    }
}
```

**P.P.S.** Есть субъективное ощущение что **это не то что вам нужно**.

Comment: Не совсем понятен 4 пункт, распишите, пожалуйста, подробнее. Что конкретно не понятно: "нерабочий jar", "каким образом идёт подмена на полноценный", "и для чего это необходимо"

Comment: Добавил пояснения в основной ответ выше.

Comment: Да, это не совсем то, мне нужно скрыть не реализацию, а возможность использовать. Но так, как я более чем уверен, что более развёрнутого и информативного ответа не последует - вы заслуженно получаете награду. Спасибо за ответ.